# Leaderboards "no internet connection try again" server offline android google play

Tags: android, google-play, leaderboard

i have this issue.

I already implemented leaderboards and achievements, both work on my android game. BUT, leaderboard is always offline.. i mean, nothing is displayed, only this, a cloud and below this " NO INTERNET CONNECTION TRY AGAIN" ... theres no information about this in google i think. anyone there knows the answer ? Thank you very much !

if you want to see by yourself the problem write here and i can give you the name of my game so you can download it from playstore or idk. ty

Answer (score 2):

well, the problem was caused due to a wrong typed LEADERBOARD ID in my eclipse android mainactivity class, detailed here:

"@Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
    startActivityForResult(gameHelper.getGamesClient().getLeaderboardIntent("LEADERBOARDIDWHICHISASECRET4YOU"), (just an int here ) );
}

i typed a wrong leaderboard id, added this "g" at the end of the id, causing an error and everytime i tried to log in leaderboards in my game it said No internet connection try again. "Wtf".